# Copy and paste Python functions in Emacs

Tags: python, emacs

I have a program that looks something like (this is a silly example to illustrate my point, what it does is not very important)

```
count = 0

def average(search_term):
    average = 0
    page = 0
    current = download(search_term, page)
    while current:
        def add_up(downloaded):
            results = downloaded.body.get_results()
            count += len(results)
            return sum(result.score for result in results)
        total = average*count
        total += add_up(current)
        average = total/count
        print('Average so far: {:2f}'.format(average))
        page += 1
        current = download(search_term, page)
```

If I have the cursor on any of the lines 8–11 and press a key combination I want Emacs to copy or kill the `add_up` function, and then I want to move the cursor to line 2 and press a key combination and paste the function there, with the correct level of indentation for the context it is pasted in.

Is this possible, and if so, how would I do that?

Comment: python-mode.el provides a bunch of copy-functions. See in menu Edit. py-copy-def for example.

Comment: Note that the mode Andreas suggests is a completely different mode from the `python-mode` that ships with Emacs.

Answer (score 3):

With python-mode.el `py-kill-def` and `yank` would do the job.
However, there are some restrictions. `py-kill-def` must be called from inside def in question. So needs to go upward from line 11 first.
Also indenting after insert poses some problems: as indent is syntax, sometimes Emacs can't know which indentation is wanted. In example below have an indent of 4 first and of 8 in `add_up` probably is not wanted - however it's legal code. After indenting first line in body of `add_up`, `py-indent-and-forward` should be convenient for the remaining.

```
def average(search_term):
    average = 0
    def add_up(downloaded):
            results = downloaded.body.get_results()
            count += len(results)
            return sum(result.score for result in results)
    page = 0
    current = download(search_term, page)
    while current:

        total = average*count
        total += add_up(current)
        average = total/count
        print('Average so far: {:2f}'.format(average))
        page += 1
        current = download(search_term, page)
```

Answer (score 1):

For this type of thing I usually use [`expand-region`](https://github.com/magnars/expand-region.el), which I choose to bind to `C-=`.

Using your example I can select the `add_up()` function by pressing `C-=` once, kill the region normally (`C-k`), move to line 2, and yank as usual (`C-y`).

Depending on what else you have configured for Python you may have to clean up some whitespace, or it may get cleaned up for you. For example, [`aggressive-indent`](https://github.com/Malabarba/aggressive-indent-mode/) would be helpful.

One manual option would be to reindent the pasted code with something like `C-x C-x M-\`.

Answer (score 1):

I've been using `smart-shift` (available in Melpa) for this sort of thing.  `global-smart-shift-mode` to enable (beware, it binds keys).  Select the block you want to move (I'd use `expand-region` like Chris), and the default keybind `C-S-c <arrow>` starts moving it.  Once you're shifting, the arrows (without `C-S-c`) shift further.  Horizontal shifts use the major mode's indent offset (`python-indent-offset` for python.el).

Comment: It sounds like `smart-shift` might be a good alternative to `drag-stuff`, which I'm using now. Thanks for the tip, I'll check it out.

Comment: Do I understand it correctly that I will still need to indent "manually" with smart-shift? What is "smart" about smart-shift?

Comment: @krq: Yes, you'll have to manually position the block.  It's "smart" because it knows about the indent offset for (many) major modes and moves horizontally according to that instead of by single columns.  That's why I like it better than `drag-stuff`.